# Azure AD v2 with Azure App Registration missing optional email claim in ID Token for directly assigned user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I am migrating my asp net core MVC web app hosted in Azure App service with Azure AD IAM from v1 to v2. When a user logs in I create/update a local user account in my database which contains the user email. The problem I have is the email claim which is now an optional claim in v2 is null so my I cannot insert a new user record in my local database.

I have been through the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) and configured my optional claims in app registration manifest etc but it does not work. I have tried all 3 claim variations (email, verified_primary_email, verified_secondary_email) but nothing comes through. However the optional claims for given_name and family_name are working as expected so the configuration must be right. How can I get email to work?

Below is my configuration and result.

**App Registration Manifest**
[image]

**App Registration Permissions**
[image]

**User Profile Setup (email configuration for directly assigned member)**
[image]
[image]

**Returned Claims**
[image]

**Startup Config (adding email scope)**

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority += "/v2.0/";
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;

    // Set the nameClaimType to be preferred_username.
    // This change is needed because certain token claims from Azure AD v1.0 endpoint
    // (on which the original .NET core template is based) are different in Microsoft identity platform endpoint.
    // For more details see [ID Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)
    // and [Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
}
```

**Signin Request (including email scope)**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/28f6d551-***-7f402200e732/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=08fde457-***-7b0eebc5e4e2
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44308%2Fsignin-oidc
&response_type=id_token
&scope=openid%20profile%20email
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=637023698441049167.ZWZlMGQ1MzctZDVmMi00OGZlLTg5YzYtMjczOWIxNzlhYjI0MzdiNGI2YzMtZTFjYi00MDMxLWFkODItNmExNDlmZTQ2MWE1&state=CfDJ8Em5zZW9XwdJkjHAUddTGuvClgDAA0NFafwsZBlTbau2qhMPcRBM36vSSzFEw7GME28L57BSQyGo8WNNzd61_bciTunD0R15oC__96_tXlWaPmk3jZkOpA2VUoiwG9XrZjfDOTQIWAzS2IuqUu5gXWU8dgK7YEfyAuRwVmCQlWqlt94HPUwMSsSJpMsdlB6HD3Tb0DaPCspo2BiYga-5LWDQ5FBnFCpxPAdLNa6LTHHNtKjUbG7YNX4oEKUBhWtxQ0Kh1CakChUFCpmMzAmBgyN5Hh_-nk3BrO3V6PrgbvDsGO6QNip5hCwiDd92gexrLYwS_UeKruPKCQMZBWZ9LnSRaNnTDN1483Abk75JiH19XPJwexmQ5aMa1KZwcde4axF-tb2cmnwWY8O4NGhRiQDSISZJAuXmHWBtAeNhnLHN659vbeiW8mo5aWD65NcfhLtio2odxvLFh3JZGoRwHCtKzu9fq8v4w7IN2f1bNb8zPdo7Lw_GREiYKs1twibIh305tja30MMRS3oAE1hKQE20A4wtmxVACuPZ201SRkFg8OHl-Iz6e4Pa41P4gT-F2jpzL1zqklDw0tzaYq68uVlqmeCY5T9vo2qkfvRuIdpyyTGu8pdi-Z6sVvIpIxPllQ
&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0
&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0
```

**Returned Token (email claim still missing)**
[image]

---

**UPDATE 2019-08-26**

I suspect the issue is with the user account instead. As a directory administrator I create the user accounts within AAD and enter the Email and Alternate Email values. However when I log in to AAD as the end user and view my profile I can see that Email field is blank and only Alternate Email field is populated as shown below. I'm not sure why the user profile is not picking up the set email address but it's a problem and I now have to find a way of getting the Alternate Email into the ID Token instead. How can this be done?

**Email Addresses in AAD**
[image]

**Email Addresses in User Profile**
[image]

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this - [How to: Provide optional claims to your Azure AD app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov yep went through that page to confirm my manifest has the correct configuration and optional claim names etc. It all looks ok to me.

Comment: May I know if you add the email scope when acquiring the token? I can get the email if I add the email scope.

Comment: @JackJia The MS documentation says "For managed users (those inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim OR, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope. For managed users, the email address must be set in the Office admin portal." so it seems you can chose to either add optional claim or add scope. However I thought I had already defined the email scope with Microsoft Graph API permission shown above. Is this correct?

Comment: You might also want to check this - the (OIDC) 'email' (delegated) permission:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-43

Answer (score 2):

Just some findings and suggestions, might not be a exact answer.

Based on the [documentation(optional claims)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) from Microsoft:
[image]

**A. The claim's name is email.**

**B. As you were migrating from V1 to V2, I just tested the V2 (For convenience, I tested with a REST API tool). By adding the openid and email scopes, I can get the email claim in id token.**

[image]

**C. Analyze the id token in jwt.io, I can get the email claim:**

[image]

I did not modify the manifest, just added openid and email scopes. You can have a try.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and have updated question with extra information. Unfortunately the email still doesn't get returned even though the email scope is included. I wonder if it's got to do with the Office Admin portal as defined by the last part of this MS statement _"For managed users (those inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim OR, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope. For managed users, the email address must be set in the Office admin portal."_ This doesn't help me as I don't have Office 365 at all.